.net console app how to check required runtime for itself at startup

I developed a console app based on .net 8.0,
then I deliver the .exe (without runtime inside) to user，
but I am not sure if the user have installed the .net 8.0 runtime to support this app, how could I make the .exe to run to check that, even user did not install the runtime
(the app start and check the runtime, if the runtime was not installed, it show the runtime download website and stop/hold)
or any other way to do it


You could use the options "PublishSingleFile" and "SelfContained", so that the whole framework will be compiled into your single *.exe file. Then you don´t have to check if the framework is installed.
